# Zip files in SFTP into a single file then download and unzip in local

Tags: python

I am writing Python code for Windows and it connects to SFTP via paramiko. In the SFTP there are around 100k individual .txt files, 4kb in size each. The current python process will read each file from SFTP and write to local which are very slow.

Is there a way to compress those files for example using zip into a single file and then download and un-compress/extract in local drive?

Thank you

Comment: The files likely need to be compressed on the server locally and then you'd download the zip. Ask the FTP admins if they can accommodate your needs.

Comment: have you looked into OpenSSH's -C option? https://linux.die.net/man/1/sftp Note that with compression you are trading CPU cycles to reduce network traffic, so make sure you are optimizing for the right bottleneck

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. The compress will have to do in remote server by combining all the txt files into a single zip file. Then I will just download the zip file. Its not compressing each single txt file.

Comment: you are thinking about file compression. SFTP  with -C will automatically compress the data before sending, and will automatically inflate it when it arrives.

Comment: Sorry if I have confused you. Actually I do not want file compression, I want to zip those files into a single zip file then download it to local.

Comment: you can certainly write python to zip the files up, transfer them, and decompress them, but the combined time to compress and decompress will almost certainly be longer than just transfering them. the issue is you have many small files, and small files suffer much more operational overhead per kb of IO than large files do. thats true whether you are copying between disks on the same system, over the network, or even between locations on the same drive (unless you are Moving them). compressing and decompressing all those tiny files will take the the same time as just copying them locally.

Comment: So since your bottleneck is IO, compression will only make that worse. if you are optimizing for network bandwidth, compression is smart, but if you are just trying to read from and write to disk faster by using a single larger file, then you will spend the same amount of time on the decompression as you gained by transferring the one big file.  in fact since you now have to compress and decompress, it may take as much as twice as long. compression is usually slower than decompression, so there is some wiggle room and edge cases where compression may be useful, but they are very case-specific.

Comment: It's possible if you have SSH access to a shell. If SFTP only then I doubt it. But what's the point? A remote archiver (e.g. `tar`) has to read all the files one by one, then you transfer the archive as a single stream, then locally you unpack and write to multiple files. Compare this to pure `sftp` getting multiple files over a single connection: the server reads multiple files, sends a stream, the client writes multiple files. Does your current Python process opens a single connection to get many files? If so, the SFTP server already acts as an archiver: it packs many files into one stream.